# Why won't Docker Desktop Start

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am trying to install Docker Desktop for Windows and once I have completed the entire process as mentioned in their official documentation, including installing and enabling the wsl 2 on Windows. However, when I try to launch the application, nothing happens except for a process showing up in the task manager. Even the taskbar icon is not coming up.
I have already browsed for information regarding this issue and tried the following solutions, but to no avail:

1. Reinstalling Docker Desktop
2. Removing the settings.json file in %APPDATA%\Roaming\Docker
3. Running Docker Installer as Administrator
4. Checking the WSL Feature in Windows Features is on.
5. Installing an older version of Docker, on which the same issue persisted

System Specifications:
Dell Inspiron 5521 running Windows 10 Pro (Version 21H1, Build 19043.1826)
Intel i7 3rd gen processor, 16GB RAM
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

This is the log file generated:
[Docker generated Log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1641dD_foF3fUO9yd3C9KxNHpHAhm7iNx/view?usp=sharing)

Can someone please guide me regarding this.

Edit: When I installed docker on my friends computer, and running the `wsl -l -v` command, he gets 3 entries namely Ubuntu, Docker desktop and docker desktop data, but on my pc it is only showing Ubuntu

Comment: With windows we never know :(

Comment: @JRichardsz Anyhow, if you have ever installed docker for windows, could you guide me for a clean installation, including proper uninstallation

Comment: It would be a pain the installation. In some cases, bios changes are required. I advice to install a vmbox with ubuntu server (without ui). You could have docker in 2 minutes with just one click https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/cf8fcec5f652a0cca432120c15d8595f#file-docker_docker_compose_oneclick_install-v1-sh  Also you could use Linux instead windows.

Comment: If you choose linux in the hole system or in a vmbox, I would be glad to help you https://github.com/jrichardsz/contact_me/discussions

Comment: @JRichardsz, I don't think my laptop will be able to handle running a docker container in vmbox. Plus I need to install docker to run flytsim, which is a drone simulator and so the same problem is there since I have a 3rd gen i7 processor

Comment: I've had similar issues that are resolved by running Docker Desktop itself (not the installer) as an administrator. It doesn't seem to detect it needs to and prompt for credentials automatically if you run as a standard user and elevate to an administrative account when needed. When I right click on the Docker Desktop shortcut and click Run as Administrator, it works though - does that work for you?

Comment: @Nick nope, I've tried running the application as an administrator, but still same issue persists. However, I am not running it via a shortcut but from my start menu, although I don't think it would make much of a difference

Comment: `common/cmd/com.docker.backend/main.go:94 +0x25
[2022-07-23T05:32:38.131207600Z][com.docker.backend.exe][F] exec: "powershell": executable file not found in %PATH%` This message appears several times in the logs. Is powershell.exe available on the %PATH% and functional?

Comment: @DrHopfen Thank you so much, that was the case, somehow I deleted that entry, docker is launching now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
common/cmd/com.docker.backend/main.go:94 +0x25 [2022-07-23T05:32:38.131207600Z][com.docker.backend.exe][F] exec: "powershell": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

This log message suggest the absence of a functional powershell on the Path. After fixing this Docker Desktop should start.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Install WSL 2**:

   - Follow the official steps on how to install WSL 2 at [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).
2. **Update WSL**:

   - Open PowerShell and run the command:

     ```
     wsl --update
     ```
3. **Uninstall Docker**:

   - If you have Docker installed, uninstall it.
4. **Delete Temporary Data**:

   - Delete the following folders:

     - C:\Users<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Docker
     - C:\Users\ProgramData\Docker
     - C:\Users\ProgramData\DockerDesktop
5. **Reinstall Docker**:

   - Reinstall Docker, and make sure to tick the option for WSL during the installation.
6. **Restart Computer**:

   - After installing Docker, restart your computer.
7. **Run Docker as Administrator**:

   - Find Docker in your programs and run it as an administrator.
8. **Run PowerShell as Administrator**:

   - Open PowerShell and run it as an administrator.
9. **Switch to Docker Daemon for WSL**:

   - Run the following command in PowerShell:

     ```
     & 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe' -SwitchDaemon
     ```
   - If it doesn't work, you may need to run the above command one or two more times.

That's it! These steps should help you fix the problem.

**Edit:**

I've encountered the same problem again, which turned out to be **related to my DNS settings**. Initially, I was using NextDNS, but the problem was resolved after I switched to Cloudflare.

It's peculiar behavior from NextDNS, as I had not set up any blocking rules. However, upon reviewing the Docker engine logs, I noticed it was attempting requests to the Docker servers, which appeared to be blocked or unfulfilled when using NextDNS (although NextDNS didn't log any blocked queries, which is odd). Consequently, the Docker engine would get caught in an infinite loop during startup, continuously trying to complete these requests.

Comment: ProgramData is at the drive root so `C:\ProgramData` not `C:\Users\ProgramData`

Comment: Just updating WSL by command `wsl --update`  worked for me. Docker engine successfully started.

Answer (score 1):

As this is one of the main Google hits for "Docker Desktop doesn't start", let me also add another potential solution here for future readers: your user was not added to the `docker-users` group yet. As explained in the [Docker installation documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/#install-interactively), if the current user is not an administrator, the current user must be added to the `docker-users` group for Docker to work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because an instance of Docker Desktop is running in the background, try opening you Task Manager/Activity Monitor, searching for "Docker Desktop", then quitting all of those processes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried This ways that i searched in Q&A forums and communities :

1. checked my BIOS Setup for Virtualization Setting
2. Install Hyper-V feature(in Win11 named Hypervisor)
3. trying to Reinstall & Update WSL
4. Delete %AppDate% files of Docker
5. Reinstall Docker
6. Starting Docker and Hyper-v Services Manually

But the final way that helped me was:

> installing lower version of Docker instead of latest version(I've installed 4.12 instead 4.27)

and it finally properly worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue where once I open the docker desktop in admin mode, it was not opening(tried restarting and opening it again but the issue still remained the same) and in services docker desktop was not running, I tried starting it in services and then try to open but nothing worked for me.

The solution that worked for me is:
I have deleted below folders in my machine

1. C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Docker
2. C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop

After deleting the above folders I have restarted my machine and tried to open docker desktop in admin mode and it worked